# Light switch with 9 wires

Tags: electrical, switch, light-fixture

I tried to install a dimmer today in the dining area and found my switch is very over complicated. The switch only controls one ceiling light but has nine wires inside.

The 3 white wires are all just connected to each other. Same with the 3 ground wires. Two black wires currently connect to the bottom of the switch and one to the top.

Can I install a dimmer here and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not overly complicated and is quite typical.

The part of the old switch with two black wires: Remove both wires, splice them with a wire nut and one of the black wires from the dimmer.

The other single wire on the switch: Splice with the other black wire from the dimmer.

The green form the dimmer goes to the ground(s).

LEAVE EVERYTHING ELSE ALONE.